# Why LoadUserProfile() fails with error 5 "Denied Access" in this code running in system service?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have a piece of code as below running in my system level Windows service. If I add CreateEnvironmentBlock() and CreateProcessAsUser() to the code, that works. But I use "LoadUserProfile()", it fails with error 5 which should mean "Access Denied". Please help to check what is missing. What I want is to retrieve a user level registry value from this system service. The comment in the code is another way, but also failed to retrieve user level registry value.

```
void GetUserRegistry()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN

    DWORD lastError = 0;

    DWORD sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    qInfo() << "Session ID = " << sessionId;

    wchar_t* ppUserName[100];
    DWORD sizeOfUserName;
    WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSUserName, ppUserName, &sizeOfUserName);
    qInfo() << "Windows User Name = " << QString::fromWCharArray(*ppUserName);

    std::wstring strValueOfBinDir = L"Unknown Value";
    // LONG regOpenResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    HANDLE hUserToken = NULL;
    HANDLE hFakeToken = NULL;

    if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, &hUserToken))
    {
         if (DuplicateTokenEx(hUserToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 0, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hFakeToken) == TRUE)
         {
            qInfo() << "Before ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()......";
            if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hFakeToken))
            {
                HKEY hKey;

                // regOpenResult = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_READ, &hKey);

                PROFILEINFO profileInfo;
                ZeroMemory( &profileInfo, sizeof( PROFILEINFO ) );
                profileInfo.dwSize = sizeof( PROFILEINFO );
                profileInfo.lpUserName = *ppUserName;
                // wchar_t roamingPath[] = L"C:\\Users\\Finix";  // L"C:\\Users\\Finix\\AppData\\Roaming";
                // profileInfo.lpProfilePath = roamingPath;

                if (LoadUserProfile(hFakeToken, &profileInfo))
                {
                    HANDLE hProfile = profileInfo.hProfile;

                    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                                 TEXT("Software\\Baidu\\BaiduYunGuanjia"),
                                 0,
                                 KEY_READ,
                                 &hKey);

                    GetStringRegKey(hKey, TEXT("installDir"), strValueOfBinDir, TEXT("Unknown"));

                    UnloadUserProfile(hFakeToken, hProfile);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastError = GetLastError();
                }

                RevertToSelf();

            }
            else
            {
                qCritical() << "Failed to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser...";
            }

            CloseHandle(hFakeToken);
        }
        else
        {
            qCritical() << "Failed to call DuplicateTokenEx...";
        }

        CloseHandle(hUserToken);
    }
    else
    {
        qCritical() << "Failed to get the user token of session " << sessionId;
    }

    if (lastError)
    {
        qCritical() << "Failed to LoadUserProfile(), The ERROR is " << lastError;
    }

//    if (regOpenResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
//    {
//        qCritical() << "Failed to call RegOpenCurrentUser(), Error is " << regOpenResult;
//    }

    qInfo() << "The value of Registry is " << QString::fromWCharArray( strValueOfBinDir.c_str() );

#endif
}
```

Comment: To be simple, the call is: WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() + WTSQueryUserToken() + DuplicateTokenEx() + ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() + LoadUserProfile() .  Why LoadUserProfile() fails with error 5? Before call LoadUserProfile(), what should be done? I have done something as above code shown. Did I miss something?

Comment: You are declaring a pointer to character array `wchar_t* ppUserName[100]`. You must change it to `wchar_t ppUserName[100];` However there might be other errors.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The code above is correct. The 4th argument of WTSQuerySessionInformation() is "LPWSTR * ", so it is a pointor to a pointor. And, as I mentioned, this program works if change LoadUserProfile() to "CreateEnvironmentBlock() + CreateProcessAsUser()". It means all the rest part is good but the call to LoadUserProfile() fails.

Comment: Then declare it as `wchar_t* pUsername;` and pass `&pUserName` to the function. Free it when finished. The way you have it setup right now doesn't make sense. Doesn't it work if you just use `RegOpenCurrentUser` by itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you *can't* call `LoadUserProfile` is that you're impersonating the user.  `LoadUserProfile` requires admin privilege, i.e., you should call it in your own context, not in the impersonated context.  It isn't a function for a user to load their own profile, ordinarily the system calls it on the user's behalf.

The reason you *shouldn't* call `LoadUserProfile` is that the user is already logged on, so the profile will already be loaded.  We *know* the user in question is logged on, because `WTSQueryUserToken` cannot be used to obtain tokens for users that aren't.

(Well, there may be edge cases where the user is currently being logged on or off.  But calling the `LoadUserProfile` function during a logon/logoff is probably unwise in any case.)

If you just want to open a logged-on user's registry hive, use [`RegOpenCurrentUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724894).  (Note that you *do* want to use impersonation with this function, as documented.)

Comment: I note that you say you've tried `RegOpenCurrentUser` and it didn't work.  I recommend that you post a separate question about that, including the code and a detailed description of how it failed.

Comment: See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141121-00/?p=43563/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @HarryJohnston. It works after I adjust some parameter of RegOpenKeyEx(). For the blog you attached, I also did a test. It looks like what the blog said is not correct. After impernating, I can get active user's one special user registry hive; then, after impersonating ends, I call the code again, it cannot get the same hive any more.

Comment: Do you mean using HKEY_CURRENT_USER or using the key returned by RegOpenCurrentUser?  According to your latest question, using HKEY_CURRENT_USER *wasn't* working, and that's what the blog post says.  Using the key returned by RegOpenCurrentUser (as shown in the accepted answer to your latest question) should always work if you are impersonating.

Comment: Ah, yes, @HarryJohnston, I think you are right. And I used the key returned by RegOpenCurrentUser.